# Laravel PragmaRX tracker throwing ErrorException in RepositoryManager.php

Tags: php, laravel, tracker, visitor-statistic, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to add PragmaRX tracker to my Laravel 5.1 application but after have followed the installation instructions on github it doesn't work and on every page that I try to visit I get this:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
ErrorException in RepositoryManager.php line 244:
Trying to get property of non-object
in RepositoryManager.php line 244
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/pragmarx/tracker/src/Data/RepositoryManager.php', '244')
at call_user_func(array(object(HandleExceptions), 'handleError'), '8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/pragmarx/tracker/src/Data/RepositoryManager.php', '244') in Handler.php line 63
at Handler->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/pragmarx/tracker/src/Data/RepositoryManager.php', '244', array()) in RepositoryManager.php line 244
at RepositoryManager->getCurrentUserAgent() in Tracker.php line 90
at Tracker->getSessionData() in Tracker.php line 420
at Tracker->checkCurrentUser() in ServiceProvider.php line 576
at ServiceProvider->PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\{closure}(object(Request), null)
at call_user_func_array(object(Closure), array(object(Request), null)) in Dispatcher.php line 221
at Dispatcher->fire('router.before', array(object(Request), null), true) in Dispatcher.php line 164
at Dispatcher->until('router.before', array(object(Request), null)) in Router.php line 1033
at Router->callFilter('before', object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 229
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 118
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 86
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

This is my config/tracker.php file:

```
return [

    /**
     * Enable it?
     */
    'enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Robots should be tracked?
     */
    'do_not_track_robots' => false,

    /**
     * Which environments are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_environments' => [
        // defaults to none
    ],

    /**
     * Which routes names are not trackable?
     */
    'do_not_track_routes' => [
        'tracker.stats.*',
    ],

    /**
     * The Do Not Track Ips is used to disable Tracker for some IP addresses:
     *
     *     '127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.1'
     *
     * You can set ranges of IPs
     *     '192.168.0.1-192.168.0.100'
     *
     * And use net masks
     *     '10.0.0.0/32'
     *     '172.17.0.0/255.255.0.0'
     */
    'do_not_track_ips' => [
        //'127.0.0.0/24' /// range 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.255
    ],

    /**
     * Log every single access?
     *
     * The log table can become huge if your site is popular, but...
     *
     * Log table is also responsible for storing information on:
     *
     *    - Routes and controller actions accessed
     *    - HTTP method used (GET, POST...)
     *    - Error log
     *    - URL queries (including values)
     */
    'log_enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Log SQL queries?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries' => false,

    /**
     * If you prefer to store Tracker data on a different database or connection,
     * you can set it here.
     *
     * To avoid SQL queries log recursion, create a different connection for Tracker,
     * point it to the same database (or not) and forbid logging of this connection in
     * do_not_log_sql_queries_connections.
     */
    'connection' => 'tracker',

    /**
     * Forbid logging of SQL queries for some connections.
     *
     * To avoid recursion, you better ignore Tracker connection here.
     *
     * Please create a separate database connection for Tracker. It can hit
     * the same database of your application, but the connection itself
     * has to have a different name, so the package can ignore its own queries
     * and avoid recursion.
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_sql_queries_connections' => [
        'tracker'
    ],

    /**
     * Also log SQL query bindings?
     *
     * Log must be enabled for this option to work.
     */
    'log_sql_queries_bindings' => false,

    /**
     * Log events?
     */
    'log_events' => false,

    /**
     * Which events do you want to log exactly?
     */
    'log_only_events' => [
        // defaults to logging all events
    ],

    /**
     * What are the names of the id columns on your system?
     *
     * 'id' is the most common, but if you have one or more different,
     * please add them here in your preference order.
     */
    'id_columns_names' => [
        'id'
    ],
    /**
     * Do not log events for the following patterns.
     * Strings accepts wildcards:
     *
     *    eloquent.*
     *
     */
    'do_not_log_events' => [
        'illuminate.log',
        'eloquent.*',
        'router.*',
        'composing: *',
        'creating: *',
    ],

    /**
     * Do you wish to log Geo IP data?
     *
     * You will need to install the geoip package
     *
     *     composer require "geoip/geoip":"~1.14"
     *
     * And remove the PHP module
     *
     *     sudo apt-get purge php5-geoip
     *
     */
    'log_geoip' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log the user agent?
     */
    'log_user_agents' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log your users?
     */
    'log_users' => true,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log devices?
     */
    'log_devices' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log HTTP referers?
     */
    'log_referers' => true,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log url paths?
     */
    'log_paths' => true,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log url queries and query arguments?
     */
    'log_queries' => false,

    /**
     * Do you wish to log routes and route parameters?
     */
    'log_routes' => true,

    /**
     * Log errors and exceptions?
     */
    'log_exceptions' => true,

    /**
     * A cookie may be created on your visitor device, so you can have information
     * on everything made using that device on your site.    *
     */
    'store_cookie_tracker' => true,

    /**
     * If you are storing cookies, you better change it to a name you of your own.
     */
    'tracker_cookie_name' => 'mywebsite_it',

    /**
     * Internal tracker session name.
     */
    'tracker_session_name' => 'tracker_session',

    /**
     * ** IMPORTANT **
     *   Change the user model to your own.
     */
    'user_model' => 'App\User',

    /**
     * You can use your own model for every single table Tracker has.
     */

    'session_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Session',

    'log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Log',

    'path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Path',

    'query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Query',

    'query_argument_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\QueryArgument',

    'agent_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Agent',

    'device_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Device',

    'cookie_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Cookie',

    'domain_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Domain',

    'referer_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Referer',

    'route_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Route',

    'route_path_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePath',

    'route_path_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\RoutePathParameter',

    'error_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Error',

    'geoip_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\GeoIp',

    'sql_query_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQuery',

    'sql_query_binding_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBinding',

    'sql_query_binding_parameter_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryBindingParameter',

    'sql_query_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SqlQueryLog',

    'connection_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Connection',

    'event_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\Event',

    'event_log_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\EventLog',

    'system_class_model' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Models\SystemClass',

    /**
     * Laravel internal variables on user authentication and login.
     */
    'authentication_ioc_binding' => 'auth', // defaults to 'auth' in Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth

    'authenticated_check_method' => 'check', // to Auth::check()

    'authenticated_user_method' => 'user', // to Auth::user()

    'authenticated_user_id_column' => 'id', // to Auth::user()->id

    'authenticated_user_username_column' => 'email', // to Auth::user()->email

    /**
     * Enable the Stats Panel?
     */
    'stats_panel_enabled' => true,

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes before filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_before_filter' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes after filter
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_after_filter' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel routes middleware
     *
     */
    'stats_routes_middleware' => '',

    /**
     * Stats Panel template path
     */
    'stats_template_path' => '/templates/sb-admin-2',

    /**
     * Stats Panel base uri.
     *
     * If your site url is http://wwww.mysite.com, then your stats page will be:
     *
     *    http://wwww.mysite.com/stats
     *
     */
    'stats_base_uri' => 'stats',

    /**
     * Stats Panel layout view
     */
    'stats_layout' => 'pragmarx/tracker::layout',

    /**
     * Stats Panel controllers namespace
     */
    'stats_controllers_namespace' => 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\Controllers',
];
```

This is my config/database.php:

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'tracker' => 'tracker',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],



        'tracker' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
            'port'     => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan tracker:updateparser
```

This worked for me.

Comment: `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "tracker:updateparser" is not defined.
Did you mean this?
    tracker:tables`